# Ag-grid: iteratively need to selectNode or select rows for 10,000 records in a tree grid

Tags: treeview, ag-grid

tree node structure:

```
{
  proto: {},
  allChildrenCount: 504,
  childIndex: 0,
  children: [],
  childrenAfterFilter: [],
  childrenAfterSort: [],
  description: "Google",
  expanded: false,
  firstChild: true,
  group: true,
  id: 1,
  keyId: "100047832",
  lastChild: false,
  level: 1,
  name: "Google",
  parent: {},
  rowHeight: 25,
  rowTop: 25,
}
```

In above, I am creating tree of n-number of nodes where parent as given above node i.e. company name: google which having 504 dept or 504 child companies.
I am populating whole tree structure in a grid, but to select all nodes iteratively:
code:

```
$scope.gridOptions.api.forEachNode(function (node) {
    $scope.gridOptions.api.selectNode(node, true);
});
```

Time taken to select all: 1 min.

could you please suggest a better way to iterate and reduce the time to select n-number of nodes in ag-grid.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to select all data, you can try:

```
$scope.gridOptions.api.selectAll()
```

Comment: Hi @Sean Landsman, Thanks for the response, but my scenario , each node has having checkbox and I am selecting node by iteration on front-end. suppose user output & tree-data node selection:
 var jsonValue=JSON.stringify($scope.savedValues); 
 /*$scope.savedValues="[{"name":"Aufsichtsrat","keyId":"100047833"},{"name":"CEO office","keyId":"100048057"},{"name":"Finance, Risk, Actuarial & Accounting","keyId":"100048163"}]" */
  $scope.gridOptions.api.forEachNode( function (node) {          
if(jsonValue.indexOf(node.keyId)>0){
  $scope.gridOptions.api.selectNode(node, true);
           });

Comment: my ag-grid version: ag-grid v3.3.3 and I am using angular 1.x . Please suggest the optimum way to reduce till 2-3 sec. currently it is taking 60 sec. or more as the selection of nodes getting increased by user on front-end(development environment browser Internet Explorer 11.0.36)
thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check this, I have been facing exactly this problem:  https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree/issues/424